# Prove/Disprove this function is surjective

Tags: functions

I'm having difficulty with figuring out an approach to solving this problem from my textbook. I understand what makes a function surjective, but that's understanding what the range is. Most examples I see proving or disproving "surjectivity" have more specific domains/codomains than just "sets".

*Let X be a set. Define a map X → X × X by d(x) = (x, x).*

*Is d(x) surjective?*

Comment: Is every element in $X\times X$ of the form $(x,x)$?

Comment: This is surjective if $X$ has one element.

Comment: To get a handle use so specific domains/codomains as examples.  Is $d:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ via $d(x) = (x,x)$ surjective.  Is $d:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ via $d(n) =(n,n)$ surjective.  Is $d:\{a,b,c\}\to \{a,b,c\}\times\{a,b,c\}$ via $d(k)= (k,k)$ surjective.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this is the only context provided for solving the problem. The hint in the back of the textbook says the answer is "no" if X has more than one element.

Comment: "unfortunately this is the only context provided for solving the problem."  Well, it's more than adequate. "The hint in the back of the textbook says the answer is "no" if X has more than one element."  That's a good hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be any set.

Let $(a,b) \in X \times X$.  (i.e. $a \in X, b\in X$).

Question is: Is there/must there be a $c \in X$ so that $d(c) = (a,b)$.

Well, $d(c) = (c,c)$ and so if $(c,c) = (a,b)$ then $c =a$ and $c =b$.

So for every $a,b\in X$ does there exist a $c \in X$ so that $c=a$ and $c = b$?

If $a \ne b$ then .... no.

So $X$ has more than $1$ element then $d$ is not surjective.

But if $X = \{x\}$ then $X \times X = \{(x,x)\}$ and $d = \{(x,(x,x))\}\subset X\times(X\times X)$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ has more than one element, say $x$ and $y$ are two different elements of $X$, then $(x,y)$ is not in the range, so the answer is no.

If $X$ has at most one element, then the answer is rather trivially yes.